# Properties Separators in File Infotips

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

How to add separators in Windows file infotips via Regedit? I'm familiar with editing infotips like "size", "author", "comments", but it seems to be a Windows tradition to make the infotip more and more messy as more items are added (probably to discourage further additions).

I remember seeing something like "System.InfotipSeparator" in the past but I can't find it again. If there is a simple way to separate infotip items into columns, help would also be appreciated.

**edit 1**:
Currently the only (and very low practice) way I know to achieve this is to manually add separators by hiding the property title with "~" and inserting "——" into your content, like

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze3ip.jpg)

**edit 2**: I found again the MS page [where](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-register-custom-properties-and-layout-for-your-file-type) it seems to be giving the answer, but it still doesn't work and probably "~System.LayoutPattern.PlaceHolder" is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've always seen every property on a separate line. Perhaps you're thinking of the `System.PropGroup.<GroupName>` properties that act as separators in the `FullDetails` proplist???

Comment: Hi Keith Miller. I really wish Microsoft had split the InfoTip lines like they did in FullDetails, but that's not the case unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Adding separators is not possible with existing Windows infotip menus,
only possible with cascading menu items that you added to the context-menu
for some file-type. Such a menu is defined via the registry.

An example is given in the article
[Creating Cascading Menu Items in Windows Explorer 7, 8, 8.1 & 10](https://blog.sverrirs.com/2014/05/creating-cascading-menu-items-in.html),
where the following menu is created:

[image]

A separator is added here after Main Action by adding the following
to the item's definition in the registry:

```
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000040
```

For detailed information see Microsoft's article
[Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers?redirectedfrom=MSDN#cascading_extended).

It's possible to modify the infotip when hovering over a shortcut
in the Windows environment. See the article
[How to Customize Shortcut Infotip Details in Windows 10](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-10-customize-shortcut-infotip-details/).

Comment: It's not about cascading menus and I've stated that I'm familiar with editing infotip items via regedit.

Comment: Good, because these are the only options.

Comment: Anyway, I really appreciate your attempt. I was used to using "SeparatorBefore(After)" for cascading menus, but your tip added more knowledge to my base.

Comment: The help did not apply to the scope of the proposed problem, but thanks again for the attempt.

Comment: Nobody can help with the impossible.

Comment: Well, proving something is impossible already is some help, but I'm still not convinced of the impossibility.

Comment: There were several posts already on our site on the subject. With successive Windows versions, Explorer is becoming more and more difficult to customize.